# Middle click on AJAX link MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an AJAX link that currently loads a partial view into a div.  If I use middle click on that link, it will open a new window with the html contents of that partial view only (i.e. no layout, css, scripts, etc).  I would like to wire up middle click to open up a new tab but with the whole contents of the web site AND the partial that normally gets loaded by that AJAX call.  I've tried some things attempting to catch middle click and doing a call to a different action that does load the entire layout but middle click is hard to work with in Firefox so that won't really work.  For example:

```
$('#myLink').click(function(e){
        if( e.which == 2 ){
            console.log("middle click");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Firefox doesn't catch that, although it does catch e.which == 1 (left click). Same goes for e.button.

Is there any way to catch this perhaps on the server and redirect to an action that renders the full page as opposed to only the partial?  Or any other solution?  Thanks!

Comment: I'd still be interested in any solutions where I'd be able to deal with this server side, perhaps through reading headers or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .mousedown instead of .click ^_^

check it out here:

http://jsfiddle.net/C5R7E/2/

Answer (score 0):

Have you considering having the link point to the your full view by default, and then having the JavaScript only load the partial view when the user left clicks?  I find it more graceful to focus on the specific functionality you want to create than recreate standard behaviors.

Comment: I marked the other reply as the answer, since it solves my specific problem.  However, thanks for your reply, I think in the future I'll try going this route instead, it seems like it would be much easier.